# Subclass UIView to show boxes on the current view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uistoryboard, subclassing

I am attempting to subclass UIView to allow me to draw six small boxes on the single view controller for my app - the idea being I will display text using labels on top of these 6 boxes.

I have created a new objective-c class subclassing `UIView`, entered the code to set the size/colour/position of the boxes & finally applied the custom class to the 'View' in the my storyboard by replacing `UIVie`w with the name of my class in the `Custom Class` section of the identity inspector (this is a single view app btw) but when I run the app nothing appears (besides what was already in the storyboard!) - if I use the same code in a completely blank app the 6 boxes appear! So I guess I am missing something... here is part of my code for the boxes:

```
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.611, 0.505, 0.321, 0.8);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(53, 271, 37, 52));
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(141, 271, 37, 52));
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(229, 271, 37, 52));
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(52, 399, 37, 52));
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(140, 399, 37, 52));
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(229, 399, 37, 52));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description of what you want (not your problem), don't bother. Instead, add the labels (or text fields) as subviews and use their background colour and their layer border properties to create the UI look you want.

In your current code, `drawRect:` should be calling super.

Comment: According to apple docs "If you subclass UIView directly, your implementation of this method does not need to call super.However, if you are subclassing a different view class, you should call super at some point in your implementation." so no need of [super drawRect]

Comment: I never even thought of using the background of the label to set the colour... no idea why... obviously over thinking things :( that works perfectly though so thank you :)